# Using OpenGL to perform video compositing with YUV color format - performance

Tags: opengl, video-processing, fragment-shader

I have written a C/C++ implementation of what I term a "compositor" (I come from a video background) to composite/overlay video/graphics on the top of a video source.  My current compositor implementation is rather naive and there is room for CPU optimization improvements (ex: SIMD, threading, etc).

I've created a high-level diagram of what I am currently doing:

[image: overlay diagram]

The diagram is self explanatory. Nonetheless, I'll elaborate on some of the constraints:

- The main video always comes served in an 8-bit YUV 4:2:2 packed format
- The secondary video (optional) will come served in either an 8-bit YUV 4:2:2 or YUVA 4:2:2:4 packed format.
- The output from the overlay must come out in an 8-bit YUV 4:2:2 packed format

Some other bits of information:

- The number of graphics inputs will vary; it may (or may not) be a constant value.
- The colour format of the Graphics can be pinned to either ARGB or YUVA format (ie. I can provide it as you see fit). At the moment, I pin it to YUVA to keep a consistent colour format.

The potential of using OpenGL and accompanying shaders is rather appealing:

1. No need to reinvent the wheel (in terms of actually performing the composition)
2. The possibility of using GPU where available.

My concern with using OpenGL is performance. Looking around on the web, it is my understanding that a YUV surface would be converted to RGB internally; I would like to minimize the number of colour format conversions and ensure optimal performance. Without prior OpenGL experience, I hope someone can shed some light and suggest if I'm about to venture down the wrong path.

Perhaps my concern relating to performance is less of an issue when using a dedicated GPU? Do I need to consider separate code paths:

- Hardware with GPU(s)
- Hardware with only CPU(s)?

Additionally, am I going to struggle when I need to process 10-bit YUV?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to treat YUV as independent channels throughout. OpenGL shaders will be calling them r, g, and b, but it's just data that can be treated as whatever you want.

Most GPUs will support 10 bits per channel (+ 2 alpha bits). Various will support 16 bits per channel for all 4 channels but I'm a little rusty here so I have no idea how common support is for this. Not sure about the 4:2:2 data, but you can always treat it as 3 separate surfaces.

- The number of graphics inputs will vary; it may (or may not) be a constant value.

This is something I'm a little less sure about. Shaders like this to be predictable. If your implementation allows you to add each input iteratively then you should be fine.

As an alternative suggestion, have you looked into OpenCL?